# BGAppRefreshTask never called

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift5

BGAppRefreshTask is not working, I marked the option of background fetch capability
The method inside BGTaskScheduler.shared.register is never called

my code:

```
   private let appRefreshTaskId = "internetDisconnectionsId"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
                BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: appRefreshTaskId, using: nil) { task in
                    self.handleAppRefreshTask(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
                    
                }

                
            }
        
       
        return true
    }

    
    func handleAppRefreshTask(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        task.expirationHandler = {
         print("Background Working")
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        }
    }
    
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
       func scheduleAppRefresh() {
           let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: appRefreshTaskId)

           request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2 * 60) // Refresh after 2 minutes.

           do {
               try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
           } catch {
               print("Could not schedule app refresh task \(error.localizedDescription)")
           }
       }
    
    

    
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).scheduleAppRefresh()
        print("called")
       }
```

I would love to understand where I am wrong

Comment: Did you add `internetDisconnectionsId` to your Info.plist under the key `BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers`?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what else to try  @birkoof

Comment: Maybe your print statements don't work. Try storing a debug string inside UserDefaults when the task is executed, created, failed etc. and display it somewhere in a label inside the app

Comment: you can also force call a task when in development, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development), so you don't have to wait for the system to call it

Comment: I tried, unfortunately it is not activated, I don't know how to solve it @birkoof

Comment: Did you find a fix?